# How to assign a "reseting" group number by the second grouping variable in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-preprocessing

My data looks like this:

| Measurement | Compound | Measure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 111 |
| 1 | A | 222 |
| 1 | B | 333 |
| 1 | B | 444 |
| 2 | C | 555 |
| 2 | C | 666 |
| 2 | D | 777 |
| 2 | D | 888 |

And I'm trying to assign a "reseting" group number based on Compound:

| Measurement | Compound | Measure | Compound_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 111 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 222 | 1 |
| 1 | B | 333 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 444 | 2 |
| 2 | C | 555 | 1 |
| 2 | C | 666 | 1 |
| 2 | D | 777 | 2 |
| 2 | D | 888 | 2 |

Didn't come up with the solution on dplyr group_by.

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Measurement = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  Compound = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", 'D'),
  Measure = 111 * 1:8
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great start. My original example table was a bit too simplified. Now added one more column and few more rows to get the proper idea. –

Comment: There can be random number of rows for each measurement, not necessarily 2*X + 2*Y.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your updates.

Comment: I have updated your question by providing R code to create your example data frame. Please notice that it would be great if you can provide a reproducible example next time.

Comment: Sure, I will. Something is naturally more obvious to one who sees the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Measurement) %>%
  mutate(Compound_order = as.integer(factor(Compound,
                                            levels = unique(Compound)))) %>%
  ungroup()

dat2
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#   Measurement Compound Measure Compound_order
#         <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>          <int>
# 1           1 A            111              1
# 2           1 A            222              1
# 3           1 B            333              2
# 4           1 B            444              2
# 5           2 C            555              1
# 6           2 C            666              1
# 7           2 D            777              2
# 8           2 D            888              2
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Measurement = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  Compound = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", 'D'),
  Measure = 111 * 1:8
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table`solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, Compound_order := rleid(Compound), by = .(Measurement)]
#    Measurement Compound Measure Compound_order
# 1:           1        A     111              1
# 2:           1        A     222              1
# 3:           1        B     333              2
# 4:           1        B     444              2
# 5:           2        C     555              1
# 6:           2        C     666              1
# 7:           2        D     777              2
# 8:           2        D     888              2
```

Comment: Thank you for the great start. My original example table was a bit too simplified. Now added one more column and few more rows to get the proper idea.

Comment: updated according to new sample data

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(
  measument = c(1,1,2,2),
  compount = c(letters[1:4])
)

dat %>% group_by(measument) %>% 
  mutate(compount_order = 1:n())
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   measument [2]
#>   measument compount compount_order
#>       <dbl> <chr>             <int>
#> 1         1 a                     1
#> 2         1 b                     2
#> 3         2 c                     1
#> 4         2 d                     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the great start. My original example table was a bit too simplified. Now added one more column and few more rows to get the proper idea. –